# Strictly stationary but not weakly stationary (not i.i.d case)

Tags: math, statistics

I am trying to find an example of strictly stationary but not weakly stationary.
Plus, this example should not be i.i.d time series data.
How can I find this example?

Comment: can you elaborate`

Comment: I.i.d process with standard Cauchy distribution is strictly stationary. But it is not weakly stationary as the second moment is not finite. I wanted to find a similar example without using the i.i.d process.